# About contact nodes

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

This works normally, but it doesn't works when more than one contact at the same time. How can i fix it?

```
if (collision == (ballRightCategory | enemyCategory)) {
        SKNode *node = contact.bodyA.node;
        if (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == enemyCategory) {
            node = contact.bodyB.node;
        }
            [[Sound sharedInstance] playSoundEffect:@"scoreSound.wav"];
            [node removeFromParent];
            [self gainScore];
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Please elaborate. Consider that any body may be bodyB at one time, but another time it may be bodyA. There's no guarantee that the same body will always be bodyB in collision with a specific other body.

Comment: Ball removes the Enemies. It works when 1 enemy contact to ball, But it doesn't works when more than one contact at the same time.